# How to shuffle a collection of integers so that the output is same in both C++ and Java?

Tags: java, c++, c++11, visual-c++, random

I am porting a piece of code from C++ to Java. In C++, I shuffle a `vector<int>` as below:

```
std::vector<int> integers(10); //Size is not constant and can change.
std::iota(std::begin(std::begin(integers), std::end(integers), 0); //fills the vector with integers from 0 to 9
std::mt19937 gen;
gen.seed(integers.size());
std::shuffle(std::begin(integers), std::end(integers), gen);
```

After doing some reseach, I found out that, java uses Linear Congruential Generator (LCG) to generate random numbers.
In order to use same parameters used by Java.util.random for LCG, I changed my random number generator engine to (According to this wikepedia page [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use)):

```
std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned long, 0x5DEECE66D, 11, 281474976710655>  engine(10);
```

> C++ shuffled result : 6,9,0,3,8,4,1,2,7,5

Here is the correspoding Java code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList(10);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    array.add(i, i);
}
Collections.shuffle(array,  new Random(10));
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    System.out.print(array.get(i));
}
```

> Java shuffled result: 9,7,8,0,1,4,5,2,6,3

1. Is there a way to make C++ stadard random number generators to
   behave the same way as of Java or vice versa?
2. Is there any other (probably simpler) approach I could take to solve
   this problem? I don't mind changing my existing C++ code.

Comment: If you are wanting a random order, then surely the results should be different

Comment: I want to know.

Comment: The random number generator is only part of the issue. Are you certain that Java and the C++ library implement the same shuffle algorithm?

Comment: Use JNI to do it. Have the C++ side OR the Java side generate the numbers and pass it to each other via JNI. The real question is that if it is random, why should it be the same?

Comment: @Brandon Because they have the same seed.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Not necessarily! I could write my own shuffling algorithm which behaves same for both C++ and Java when seeded with same input. So my questing is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: @Blastfurnace probably shuffling algorithms might be different but the solution to my problem starts with at least having to generate same random numbers.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for your suggestion. I am not sure if I want to go down that road as of now. But yes it would surely help me solve my problem.

Comment: That Wikipedia page says the Java LCG returns bits 47..16. I have a C++ random engine based on `std::linear_congruential_engine` [posted here on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/cg5Db4). Does its output match what you see with Java?

Comment: I don't agree with the downvotes on this. I think that it's a reasonable question.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Finally, someone who found this question legitimate. I think people just read the title of the question of the question and down-vote it right-away. Sorry to say but people on SO are getting little inconsiderate. At least they should give a reason for downvoting, it may help people to frame the question in a correct way.

Comment: I agree - I think that the downvoters didn't read it too carefully, but this is something that would be really useful to know how to do if you're ever in the position of having to work in multiple languages. The only point I might clarify at all (and I think that it's already clear from a careful reading, but could possibly be highlighted more) is the fact that the pseudorandom number generators should have the same results because they have the same seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write JNI code to do it.. The C++ code would look like:

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_NativeRandom_generateRandomIntegers(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, int size)
{
    std::vector<int> integers(size);
    std::iota(std::begin(integers), std::end(integers), 0);

    std::mt19937 gen;
    gen.seed(size);
    std::shuffle(std::begin(integers), std::end(integers), gen);


    jintArray result = env->NewIntArray(size);
    if (result)
    {
        env->SetIntArrayRegion(result, 0, size, &integers[0]);
        return result;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

On the Java side it would look like:

```
public class NativeRandom {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("NativeRandom.so");
    }

    public static native int[] generateRandomIntegers(int size);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] randomNumbers = generateRandomIntegers(10);
        System.out.println(randomNumbers);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A linear congruential generator, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), has several variables (modulus, multiplier, increment), which **differ across implementations**. The [parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use) used for Java and C++, as you can see by the link, are vastly different. Therefore, even if you *seeded them both identically*, they would produce different values. Therefore, there is no change in your code that would natively allow both the C++ and Java versions to produce the same random number sequence.

If you wanted a specific random sequence, your best bet is probably to find a third-party RNG library with support for these two languages, but StackOverflow frowns upon suggesting external libraries, so good luck ;)

Comment: SO doesn't frown upon suggesting external libraries. SO frowns upon questions asking for an external resource and answers that do little more than providing an external link.